# call "EOF" in Ti-83 BASIC

Tags: eof, ti-basic

Is there an EOF operator in Ti-83 Basic like in many other languages, such as C?
I know that some programmes terminate when the "On" button is pressed (much like the EOF operator, Ctrl+D, in *nix), but I haven't been able to figure out how this operation is assigned.

As a very bad example, say I have

```
:Prompt Str0
:While Str0 ≠ "EOF"
:Disp "This code works!"
:Prompt Str0
:End
```

I want it to print "This code works!" and then prompt for Str0 until I enter a key combo ("On" button, I'm guessing) that terminates the file.

Now of course there are other ways of expressing the code above that do **not** rely on EOF. I'm just trying to give a simple example of what a scenario in which EOF *might* be useful.

Comment: I don't see why this is necessary. Since the On button immediately terminates the program (and also produces an `ERR: BREAK` error, so it's not very ideal), I don't see why you would need any of that EOF business to handle it.

Comment: @user3932000 I think you're right. 2nd + Quit also seems to terminate without any messy ERR: BREAK messages. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for a way to get keypad input to end your program, there is no single function, but you can use `getKey` to write code to do it.  Here is an example of how to make a program go until a certain key combination is entered, or the program is broken.

```
:Disp "This code works!"
:While getKey ≠ 21
:End
:While getKey ≠ 31
:End
:While getKey ≠ 45
:End
:Disp "Program ending"
:Stop
```

The above code displays `"This code works!"`, then waits until 2nd, ALPHA, then CLEAR are pressed before displaying "Program ending" then quitting.  If you are unfamiliar with the `getKey` function, I recommend [this link](http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/getkey).  Good luck with your coding!

Comment: Sorry this is so late (I haven't been around for a while) but this looks very helpful. Thanks! If all goes well, I'll accept it after testing. ;)

Comment: @Fred I hope everything meets your satisfaction.  If you have any additional questions, you know where to ask!